# How to handle an exception in telebot itself

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

I want to clarify, this is an asynchronous version of telebot.

I tried various ways to catch the errors that occur. I specified the wrong token and launched the bot, but how can I handle this error, and instead of the standard message (which will be below), I want to write my error and print it to the console, this applies not only to the token, but also to all errors that may occur in Telebot itself.

```
2022-09-21 14:14:12,608 (async_telebot.py:324 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 401. Description: Unauthorized"
```

Comment: Did you try `try except`?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but this option will work if the error is not in the loop itself, but in the syntax. I don't have any syntax errors, just an error in the token, the exception doesn't work.